# How to display node's first created date

Tags: views, 8

There are options in views to display date regarding Node:

- Authored On : Displays When node was published, its modifiable, hence not a true created date.
- Changed : Displays last updated date.

Same fields are available for Content Revision, but i wonder if i can get created date of first Revision in views.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `node.getCreatedTime()` in twig is one way.

Comment: ok, but i need to do it in `Views`.

Comment: *Authored On* in Views should be identical with the node created time. There is only one value in the database. The timestamp of a revision is the date when the revision was created, not the node.

Comment: yes, hence i want to get Created date of First revision of node.

Answer (score 0):

Created date of the First revision of a node is the node creation date.